# ColdFusion OpenCSV open in-memory file

Tags: csv, coldfusion, ram, cfml, opencsv

Imagine a kind of CSV file you need to parse on the fly.

It works in local disk storage but not in ram:///

```
<cfscript>

cfhttp(
    method = "Get",
    url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&d=4&e=2&f=2016&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=2016&ignore=.csv",
    //path = "C:\CFTemp",
    path = "ram:///",
    file = "currentCSV.csv"
);

cfdirectory(
    name="files",
    action="list",
    directory="ram:///",
    recurse="true",
    type="all"
);
writeDump(files);

myfile = FileRead("ram:///currentCSV.csv");
WriteOutput("#myfile#");


fileReader = createobject("java","java.io.FileReader");
fileReader.init("ram:///currentCSV.csv");  // -ERROR

csvReader = createObject("java","com.opencsv.CSVReader");
csvReader.init(fileReader, ",");
ArrayData = csvReader.readAll();
writeDump(ArrayData);

</cfscript>
```

-ERR ram:/currentCSV.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

What's wrong in here?

ColdFusion 11, OpenCSV 3.7

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Java does not understand the file path (fileReader.init(`"ram:///currentCSV.csv"`);) you are using while reading it. It's a ColdFusion specific syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VFS or "ram:///" is a CF construct that only works with ColdFusion functions.  [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) is a java class that does not know anything about VFS. AFAIK, its constructor only accepts a [standard file path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), ie c:/path/file.txt.